# Javascript setting values in object

Tags: jquery, object

```
  var coord = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().match(/\d{1,3}\|\d{1,3}/g);
  var AantalSpeerDorp = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(2)").text());
  var AantalZwaardDorp = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(3)").text());
  var AantalBijlDorp = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text());
  var AantalScoutDorp = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(5)").text());
  var AantalLCDorp = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(6)").text());
  var AantalHcDorp = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(7)").text());
  var AantalRamDorp = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(8)").text());
  var AantalKatDorp = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(9)").text());
  var AantalEdelDorp = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(10)").text());

  var eenhedenperdorp = {};
  eenhedenperdorp[coord] = coord;
  eenhedenperdorp[coord]["speer"] = AantalSpeerDorp;
  eenhedenperdorp[coord]["zwaard"]= AantalZwaardDorp;
  eenhedenperdorp[coord]["bijl"] = AantalBijlDorp;
  eenhedenperdorp[coord]["Scout"] = AantalScoutDorp;
  eenhedenperdorp[coord]["lc"] = AantalLCDorp;
  eenhedenperdorp[coord]["hc"] = AantalHcDorp;
  eenhedenperdorp[coord]["ram"] = AantalRamDorp;
  eenhedenperdorp[coord]["kata"] = AantalKatDorp;
  eenhedenperdorp[coord]["edel"] = AantalEdelDorp;
```

As you can see I'm trying to create this object like this (all these variables are in an each function), but when I try it out I get an empty object.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(eenhedenperdorp));
```

Result: {}

What's the correct way to do this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/czGrv/

Comment: Move this line: `var eenhedenperdorp = {};` outside of the loop? Otherwise you're just creating a new object that's not visible outside of the scope of the each function every time.

Comment: I did put that outside of the loop :) I just placed it here so it would be clear what I'm trying to do. @adeneo How is this complicated? Everything is a variable, and I'm putting every variable with the corresponding numbers and types in an object. I don't know how else I could do it?

Comment: What object is `this` at the start of the code? What event are you inside of? More code please.

Comment: @user3227070 why not providing more context of your posted code, as the each loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you're not instantiating the object that you seem to want to instantiate. Change the first line of instantiation to:

```
eenhedenperdorp[coord] = {};
```

Your [coord] parameter needs to be an object itself to fill it with parameters later on in your code.

Comment: That does the trick, you're a life saver :) Thx alot! I'll accept in one minute btw

Comment: No problemo. Add some nice camel casing, it's valid in dutch too! eenhedenPerDorp

Comment: Now if you just data-drive the lookup in a loop so their code is not so long-winded... :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I am not actually completely sure what 'data-drive' means here... Although I'd be open to adding some things in my answer to make the code less long-winded. What is your proposition?

Comment: He probably means getting eq(1-10) in a loop, but I think it's nice and clear this wzy :)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. You have solved the specific problem, but the code is overly long-winded and therefore harder to maintain and should also be refactored. A loop over an array, e.g. containing the indexes and property names to set, would do the same thing in a couple lines of code (instead of dozens) and would allow more easily for future changes. I do realise that SO is more about point-scoring than education, so feel free to ignore my advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Check what you want to do.

Since you use `.match()`, `coord` will be either an array or `null` (if the match isn't good).

Your line:

```
eenhedenperdorp[coord] = coord;
```

ensures that your following object property assignments will fail, either silently (you can't do that to arrays) or violently (with a TypeError).

You probably meant:

```
eenhedenperdorp[coord] = {};
```